# Стресс тест php-fpm

Tags: php, linux

Отключаю `limit_req` в nginx и остальные псевдо-защиты, и имитирую атаку ботов на php скрипт с функцией `microtime()`:

```
ab -kc 10000 -t 10 http://mysite.com/script.php
```

Атака начинается, пулы грузят ЦП, load average растет. Проходит 10 секунд, ab выдает статистику, а пулы продолжают грузить цп еще на протяжении 3-4 минут.

В конфиге стоит:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 4
pm.max_requests = 1024
```

В процессах вижу, что пулы убиваются, создаются новые и тут же снова начинают грузить цп. Почему? Ведь стресс тест уже закончился и новые GET запросы на php скрипт не приходят. Объясните, не понимаю :(

Comment: Каков процент некорректно завершенных запросов?